Sending mail on server
I have a .NET Core project from which I need to send e-mails.
I use the Gmail server, I enabled the password per application and this is my code:
using (var message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.From = new MailAddress(mailSender);
    message.To.Add(toAddress);
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = body;

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp))
    {
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailSender, passwordSender);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        var pdfAttachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes), fileName);
        pdfAttachment.ContentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("application/pdf");
        message.Attachments.Add(pdfAttachment);

        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}

Locally everything works perfectly.
On the server, emails are never sent without obtaining useful information about them.
I tried to see the status of port 587 with this command from PowerShell:
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName smtp.gmail.com -Port 587

And I get:
AVVISO: TCP connect to (IP : 587) failed

ComputerName           : smtp.gmail.com
RemoteAddress          : IP
RemotePort             : 587
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 3
SourceAddress          : IP
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 49 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

Unlike the 465 which passes the test.
However, by changing the code to port 465, sending emails still does not work.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help me

Could you kindly check  firewall rule by using netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all | findstr "587" first ? If there is nothing show in the windows, please try to run netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 587" protocol=TCP dir=out localport=587 action=allow. Then test the application again.

This is the result shown in the window:
RemotePort:                           3587
LocalPort:                            3587

Hi @Andrea, 3587 ?

Hi Jason, yes !

Hi Andrea, have you excuted this command netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 587" protocol=TCP dir=out localport=587 action=allow ?

Yes, but it still doesn't work.

Could you kindly check the eventviewer? I mean can we find any logs when sending the email.

Unfortunately no record about this

Hi Andrea, is your Windows Server Managed by your Company ?  If yes, please contact IT Department and let them help you check.

If not, I will test it in my server by using your code snippets. Waiting for your update.

Hi Jason, it is managed by the customer, I will contact them directly. I'll update you, thank you very much.

Thanks for your reply, maybe some security policy restrict this, waiting for your reply.
